# Should I be concerned about my almost 1-year-old baby being scared to walk?

Tags: infant, development

My child will be one year old on the 15th of February, and she has not yet tried to start walking. She only pulls up on me when we are sitting on the bed or couch, but when I go to put her down on the floor she will not pull up to her feet she will pull up till she is on her knees and when I hold her hand to walk she is on her tip toes and try to go very fast. If I stand her up on the side of the bed she will cry like she was really scared.

Should I have any concerns at this point?

Comment: I think children develop differently and at different rates. My goddaughter walked at 9 months but was slow to talk. My nephew did not walk until he was 15 months but could play with a basketball (toddler-sized), and get baskets from 3 feet away at 12 months. Was he slow or gifted? If you are concerned, see your doctor, but this sounds like it is still well within normal range.

Answer (score 3):

Bill Tan, yes, your comment on crawling is a good point.. [LINK](http://www.parenting.com/article/do-babies-need-to-crawl)

> According to experts, more kids seem to be hitting numerous motor
>   (movement) development milestones later or skipping them altogether.
>   The topic is increasingly becoming controversial in the medical
>   community. While the conventional wisdom is that there's no harm in
>   skipping the crawling stage, a growing number of experts  --
>   particularly pediatric occupational therapists  -- say that crawling
>   is actually a critical developmental milestone whose long-term
>   benefits we're only now beginning to recognize.

I think your child is well within the normal range for walking. If you are concerned and have not discussed it with your doctor then ask. Children develop at different rates and unless your doctor is concerned,  I think it's fine.

I was thinking about crawling and why it is important. IMO, it is as important as walking. [LINK Why crawling is important](http://www.medcentral.org/Main/Whatssoimportantaboutcrawling.aspx)

Building the core muscles and the muscles of the arms and legs makes crossing the midline easier for children. There's even a link to Attention Deficit Disorders, when children have problems with it.

[LINK Why crossing the midline is important](https://childdevelopment.com.au/areas-of-concern/fine-motor-skills/crossing-the-bodys-midline/)

Answer (score 1):

It may be nothing, or she may have sensory sensitivities and is averse to your floor.

Children with sensory sensitivities can be averse to certain texture, sudden change in temperature etc. Most of us are to an extent, eg preference for certain fabrics due to the texture. If she is averse to your floor (eg very cold, carpeted etc), you can let her wear socks to reduce the contrast, but at the same time, do expose her to it regularly. This is a simple checklist, but please use it only as a reference. I am in no way suggesting that your child has a disorder. http://www.sensory-processing-disorder.com/sensory-processing-disorder-checklist.html

Another possibility is that she is afraid of falling down, and she associates the floor with pain. Get down to her level and give her plenty of encouragement.

If you haven't, you can also consider using interlocking foam tiles in the house for her to crawl/walk on. It is firm enough to walk on yet soft enough to fall on.